# Power Bi/Dax: Summarize table with filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this table:

```
IP  Technology  Status
IP1 T1  Passed
IP1 T1  Passed
IP1 T1  Failed
IP1 T2  Failed
IP1 T2  Failed
IP1 T2  Passed
IP2 T3  Passed
IP2 T3  Failed
IP3 T4  Passed
IP3 T4  Passed
IP3 T5  Passed
IP3 T5  Passed
IP3 T5  Passed
IP3 T5  Passed
IP3 T5  Passed
IP2 T6  Passed
IP2 T6  Passed
IP2 T6  Passed
IP2 T6  Passed
```

I have to remove some of the Technology (T2 and T6) and show the following summary table: 
(I am interested only in the ‘Passed’ results but left the ‘failed’ column for reference)

```
IP   Failed Passed  100% Passed
IP1  33%    67%     No
IP2  50%    50%     No
IP3  0%     100%    Yes
```

This is what I did:
I created two temporary tables to calculate the number of passed tests and the total number of tests:

```
Table1 =
CALCULATETABLE (
    GROUPBY (
        'Table',
        'Table'[IP],
        'Table'[Status],
        "#Passed", COUNTAX ( CURRENTGROUP (), ( 'Table'[Status] = "Passed" ) )
    ),
    'Table'[Technology] = "T1"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T3"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T4"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T5"
)
```

```
Test2 =
CALCULATETABLE (
    GROUPBY (
        'Table',
        'Table'[IP],
        "#scan", COUNTAX ( CURRENTGROUP (), ( 'Table'[IP] ) )
    ),
    'Table'[Technology] = "T1"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T3"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T4"
        || 'Table'[Technology] = "T5"
)
```

In Table1, I added the total number of tests from Table2 using LOOKUPVALUE and calculated the ‘%Passed’.

When I want to get the ‘100% Passed’ flag (Yes/No) using IF statement:

```
100% Passed = IF(%'Table Test1'[%Passed]=1,"Yes","No")
```

I get this error message:

`The following syntax error occurred during parsing: invalid token, Line1, Offset 4, %`

Is it because the ‘%Passed’ is a calculated field?  Do you know a way around?  I’ve been working on this for days and I’m getting frustrated.  Is there a more efficient way to get this result?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is `%'Table Test1'[%Passed]` defined? That doesn't appear to be a valid reference to anything.

Comment: ```%Passed = divide('Table Test1'[#Passed],'Table Test1'[#Scan]) ```

Comment: There's a `%` in front of the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer `SUMMARIZE` over `GROUPBY` although they are quite similar. You can use `ADDCOLUMNS` to add additional logic that refers to columns you calculated in your summarization to get the `100% Passed` column.

```
Summary =
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table',
            'Table'[IP],
            "% Passed", DIVIDE (
                CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Status] = "Passed" ),
                COUNTROWS ( 'Table' )
            )
        ),
        "100% Passed", IF ( [% Passed] = 1, "Yes", "No" )
    ),
    NOT ( 'Table'[Technology] IN { "T2", "T6" } )
)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: ```The expression refers to multiple columns.  Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.```

Comment: Are you trying to use this table definition as a measure or calculated column? It would throw that error if you did.

Comment: Yes, I was doing that...  I used your suggestion to create a table and it worked.  Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Apologies for coming back to this question. Do you know if there is a way to get the same results in the original table instead of creating a temporary table to calculate it? I'm asking because I need it to be more flexible and be able to filter the results by more than one dimension. I only could related 'Summary' and 'Table' using only one column.

Comment: Sure. It's rather a different question though so perhaps create a new post.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the suggestion