# Power bi Calculate ratio

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this Table:

```
Group   IP  Technology  Status
G1  IP1 T1  Passed
G1  IP1 T1  Passed
G1  IP1 T1  Failed
G1  IP1 T2  Failed
G1  IP1 T2  Failed
G1  IP1 T2  Passed
G1  IP2 T3  Passed
G1  IP2 T3  Failed
G2  IP3 T4  Passed
G2  IP3 T4  Passed
G2  IP3 T5  Passed
G2  IP3 T5  Passed
G2  IP4 T5  Passed
G2  IP4 T5  Passed
G2  IP4 T5  Passed
G2  IP2 T6  Passed
G2  IP2 T6  Passed
G2  IP2 T6  Passed
G2  IP2 T6  Passed
```

I have to exclude some of the Technology (T2 and T6) and calculate the following:

```
100%Passed =
(# unique IPs that have 100% passed) /
    (total # unique IPs I need to be able to cut it in different ways)
```

*I left the failed column for reference*

**Result by IP:**

```
IP  Failed  Passed  Passed flag
IP1 33% 67%     No
IP2 50% 50%     No
IP3 0%  100%    Yes
IP4 0%  100%    Yes
```

**Result by Technology:**

```
Technology  Failed  Passed  Passed flag
T1  33% 67%     No
T3  50% 50%     No
T4  0%  100%    Yes
T5  0%  100%    Yes
```

**Result by Technology:**

```
Group   Failed  Passed  Passed flag
G1  40% 60%     No
G2  0%  100%    Yes
```

My idea is to create two columns to count unique IPs and then create a measure to calculate the `%Passed`.

I created the following columns:

```
Numerator =
IF (
    AND (
        'Table'[Status] = "Passed",
        'Table'[Technology] IN { "T1", "T3", "T4", "T5" }
    ),
    'Table'[IP],
    ""
)
```

```
Denominator =
IF ( 'Table'[Technology] IN { "T1", "T3", "T4", "T5" }, 'Table'[IP], "" )
```

This formula works in this example but when I apply it to my working data, I get this error message:

> A single value for column ‘IP’ in the table ‘Table’ cannot be determined.  This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such a min, max, count, or sum to get a single result

Do you know why I get this error message?

Please let me know if you have a better solution to get the `100%Passed` and `100% Passed Flag` (Yes/No).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Can you please take a look at this question?

Comment: Follow up to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong here. First, the error you're getting suggests that you were trying to create a measure instead of a calculated column. Second, your `IP` column is not a number so the division wouldn't work anyway.

I'll assume that you are, in fact, trying to make a measure that goes into a visual rather than calculated columns.

Using a slicer and a measure that counts rows and `Status` on columns:

[image: Matrix Visual]

You can calculate percent passed (only including specific technologies) as follows:

```
Passed% = 
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), KEEPFILTERS ( Table1[Status] = "Passed" ) ),
        CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), ALL ( Table1[Status] ) )
    ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( Table1[Technology] IN { "T1", "T3", "T4", "T5" } )
)
```

(Note: I'm using [KEEPFILTERS](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-keepfilters-in-dax/) to add to the filter context rather than replacing it entirely.)

It's easy then to write a `100%Passed` flag measure:

```
100%Passed = 
IF ( NOT ISBLANK ( [Passed%] ), IF ( [Passed%] = 1, "Yes", "No" ) )
```

Since we've added the `Technology` filter to the measure, the tables should look like we expect even if the slicer isn't used:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  This measure works when I apply it to my example but when I tried to do the same in my report, I got this error message:
```
"KEEPFILTERS function can only be used as a top level filter argument of CALCULATE and CALCULATETABLE or with a table argument of a function performing a table scan" 
```   the problem is the second KEEPFILTERS.  Do you know what can cause it?

Comment: Try replacing `KEEPFILTERS ( [...]` with `FILTER ( Table1, [...]` or one of the constructions in the link I provided.